# Using an image as a flat backdrop?

Tags: texturing

I'm using 2.79 and Cycles render.

I'm making a flat, cartoony scene, and would like to essentially use the below image as a horizon/sky texture. I want the image to display undistorted by perspective, independent of the camera/view angle.

I attempted to do this using the World tab > image texture, but I couldn't get it to do anything like what I wanted (under most settings it just shows flat colours from the image rather than the full thing, and one setting gives a kind of distorted polar coordinates-style effect, which is again different to what I'm going for)

I have tried using textured flat planes and cylinders, but these were both hard to set up within the camera view in the way I wanted, and ended up distorting the image texture.

Sorry if this is a basic question - I have tried searching for tutorials on this but nothing I found answered my question, perhaps because I don't know the proper name for this technique.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Not sure to understand exactly what you want. But as I see it, just set the camera as orthographic.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain well enough - orthographic view would not solve my problem.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uo8UoZtwuMc&t=14s
I basically want my background to do the same thing as the background in this video. It's a 2d plane, but when the camera moves, it stays in the same position and is always viewed from head-on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the world node tree from the "window" texture coordinates (so no distortions).

Then use an image texture (not environment texture).

The image won't move when the camera moves.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is amazing! This was exactly what I was looking for - also, thank you for showing me where to find the World nodes - I had been looking for that option too. :)

Comment: FYI, if you add a vector mapping between texture coordinates and the image you can shift the image in x and y, if needed (as the linked video seems to move a little bit).

Comment: Thank you - while I was messing around I also found sliders to change the position in the Texture tab, but good to know your method too. :)

Answer (score 1):

That's the way I do it when I make my 2d animations.

I use **Import Images As Planes**, check **Shadeless**.

Put the image in front of the camera.

Select the image and the Camera and **Make Parent**.

Now the image is locked to the camera view.

[image]

Comment: Thank you - this more or less works! I am using 3D elements in my scene, so it is a little tricky getting the plane at the right distance where it still sits behind all of the 3D elements I want in shot, but I will mess around with it. :)