# Rendering Camera Image Background From Glass Refraction

Tags: rendering

I am trying to render a scene that uses Camera Image Background.

The camera is tracked and moving simulating the video. Thus I am using Image Background and hoping it would just render and appears on the Refraction.

I tested using actual Image Plane, it seems to render, but of course this is not ideal since camera is really moving.

Is there in anyways we can render Camera Image Background and having it actually appearing as Refraction in render?

[image]

[image: refraction from Camera Image Background alon does not render in camera]

Comment: I guess there ist really no problem with the plane (parented to the camera). Obviously it will give bad results because there is no depth information, but if thats good enough, do it. Cheat like an artist!

Comment: The camera images are for reference only, I'm order to have refraction you would need to use the image as world, but have the image be mapped using "window" coordinates like in this post: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/169627

Comment: Thanks I ended using Plane (make it really big) that uses Windows and that works and showing up in render behind refraction.